# Alternatives to Zend_Search_Lucene?

Tags: php, zend-search-lucene

I want to know whether there are any other libraries or modules which is a viable alternative to Zend_Search_Lucene.

Comment: Alternatives to the ZF Package or alternatives to Lucene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), a RESTful search engine service. One project I know of that uses it is [Meta CPAN](http://search.metacpan.org/), which is also [open-source](https://github.com/CPAN-API/search-metacpan-org) and performs really well for what I can tell.

Comment: Elasticsearch was wonderful to work with. I would highly recommend this to anyone who stumbles upon this post

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest Sphinx. The result on a short [benchmark:](http://jayant7k.blogspot.com/2006/06/benchmarking-results-of-mysql-lucene.html)

> Single searches are faster than that in lucene. But here we will have to consider the fact that there is no OR clause in the search. So the search engine does not have to get 2 different result sets and do a union on them. But as the concurrency of searches in increased the average time per search does not drop majorly as in lucene. Clearly pointing out that there may be concurrency issues here. Since i have not explored this to a great extent, i cannot comment on the problems related to concurrency here.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) search.  I've [had good results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315910/php-word-index-performance-and-reasonable-results/3319525#3319525) with it in the past.

Answer (score 1):

There are good alternatives.
[Google Site Search](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products_gss.html/)
[Solr](http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php/)
[Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)